# Is calling `stringstream::str()` for getting what's printed actually legal?

Tags: c++, string, iostream, stringstream

Pre-history: I'm trying to ensure that some function `foo(std::stringstream&)` consumes all data from the stream.

Answers to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662976/how-do-i-convert-from-stringstream-to-string-in-c) suggest that using `stringstream::str()` is the right way of getting content of a stringstream. I've also seen it being used to convert arbitrary type to `string` like this:

```
std::stringstream sstr;
sstr << 10;
assert(sstr.str() == std::string("10"));  // Conversion to std::string for clarity.
```

However, the notion of "content" is somewhat vague. For example, consider the following snippet:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::stringstream s;
  s << "10 20";
  int x;
  s >> x;
  std::cout << s.str() << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

[On Ideone](http://ideone.com/NihH9P) (as well as on my system) this snippet prints `10 20`, meaning that reading from `stringstream` does not modify what `str()` returns. So, my assumption is that that `str()` returns some internal buffer and it's up to `stringstream` (or, probably, its internal `rdbuf`, which is `stringbuf` by default) to handle "current position in that buffer". It's a [known thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27472658/stringstream-and-str-not-synchronized).

Looking at [`stringbuf::overflow()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringbuf/overflow/) function (which re-allocates the buffer if there is not enough space), I can see that:

> this may modify the pointers to both the input and output controlled sequences (up to all six of eback, gptr, egptr, pbase, pptr, epptr).

So, basically, there is no theoretical guarantee that writing to `stringstream` won't allocate a bigger buffer. Therefore, even using `stringstream::str()` for converting `int` to `string` is flawed: `assert(sstr.str() == std::string("10"))` from my first snippet can fail, because internal buffer is not guaranteed to be precisely of the necessary size.

**Question is**: what is the correct way of getting the "content" of `stringstream`, where "content" is defined as "all characters which could be consumed from the steream"?

Of course, one can read char-by-char, but I hope for a less verbose solution. I'm interested in the case where nothing is read from `stringstream` (my first snippet) as I never saw it fail.

Comment: Does `string str; s >> str;` read the right thing?

Comment: why do you expect `s >> x` will change content of `s`?

Comment: @LapshinDmitry it behaves similarly to standard streams and reads the first "token" only.

Comment: @pergy because it changes `s`'s behavior in the future. Basically, my expectation was that `str()` would return unconsumed data in the stream.

Comment: @yeputons I see. btw, `rdbuf()` seems to be containing unconsumed data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tellg()` function (inherited from `std::basic_istream`) to find the current input position. If it returns -1, there are no further characters to be consumed. Otherwise you can use `s.str().substr(s.tellg())` to return the unconsumed characters in `stringstream s`.

Comment: Sounds nice. Are you sure there is no need in something similar to `tellg` for "pointer to buffer's end" ([`egptr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/egptr/), presumably?)

Comment: Those functions in `streambuf` would be useful to do what you want without copying any data, but they're protected, so you can't access them. If you don't mind copying the data (as above), then the returned string terminates at the end of the buffer, so you don't need a "pointer to buffer's end"